# lodash indexBy with not uniq keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

How I can index array with not uniq keys. I try use lodash indexBy, but it gives not expected result.

```
var keys = [
  { 'dir': 'left', 'code': 97 },
  { 'dir': 'left', 'code': 100 },
  { 'dir': 'right', 'code': 50 },
  { 'dir': 'right', 'code': 51 }
];
var a = _.indexBy(keys, 'dir');
```

Result:

```
{ left: { dir: 'left', code: 100 },
  right: { dir: 'right', code: 51 } }
```

Expected result:

```
{ left: [{ dir: 'left', code: 100 }, { 'dir': 'left', 'code': 97 }],
  right: [{ dir: 'right', code: 51 }, { 'dir': 'right', 'code': 50 }] }
```

Comment: Note: `_.indexBy` is now known as `_.keyBy`(https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) for that, like this

```
console.log(_.groupBy(keys, 'dir'));
```

would print

```
{ left: [ { dir: 'left', code: 97 }, { dir: 'left', code: 100 } ],
  right: [ { dir: 'right', code: 50 }, { dir: 'right', code: 51 } ] }
```